# Rebase commits onto master when commits are already merged

Tags: git, github

[image]

Now I want "Public recompile." and "Require compatible packages for package.json" to sit on single time-line a and NOT the alternate one. All the branches local or remote got all the commits already. How would I do that

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: Because I want a clean history so that I can share the code.

Comment: I would not care about the past. You can change it but it is hard... See eg here https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

Comment: Well maybe that's why I'm here to seek help.

Comment: Does that help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/10016707/5784831. Which commit tree do you expect in the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Because I want a clean history so that I can share the code.*

Note that what you have is a "clean" Git history. "Feature bubbles" like yours show which commits were done together as a group. This is additional useful information for figuring out why a commit was made. I would recommend leaving your repository as is.

What you want to avoid are "update" merges getting the latest updates from master. These are what I call "bookkeeping" merges. They confuse the history and are not useful for archeology.

```
*   11067971 [master]
|\
| * d3adb3f merge master again
|/|
* | 1234567 another master commit
| * daf9f2d Require compatible...
| * abc1234 merge master
|/|
| * 3547419 Public recompile.
* | e0d2740 N/A
* | 6b2385f Apply Codestyles:
|/
* 08c6f59 Change vendor user...
```

Instead, use `git rebase` for updates to keep your branch history linear.

```
git checkout feature
git rebase master

 * daf9f2d [feature] Require compatible...
 * 3547419 Public recompile.
 * 1234567 [master] another master commit
 * e0d2740 N/A
 * 6b2385f Apply Codestyles:
 * 08c6f59 Change vendor user...
```

Then `git merge --no-ff` (no-fast-forward) to keep the feature bubble.

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff feature
git branch -d feature

* abcd1234 [master] merge feature
|\
| * daf9f2d Require compatible...
| * 3547419 Public recompile.
|/
* 1234567 another master commit
* e0d2740 N/A
* 6b2385f Apply Codestyles:
* 08c6f59 Change vendor user...
```

Because the merge does nothing, when you test the branch before the merge you have also tested the code after the merge. Now you only need to QA the branch once.

If you want to improve your history, use `git rebase -i` to put something in those `N/A` commit messages.

But if you want to wipe that important information out...

---

- Restore master and the branch before the merge.

This effectively undoes the merge.

```
git branch -f master e0d2740
git branch -f feature daf9f2d

   * daf9f2d [feature] Require compatible...
   * 3547419 Public recompile.
 * | e0d2740 [master] N/A
 * | 6b2385f Apply Codestyles:
 |/
 * 08c6f59 Change vendor user...
```

- Rebase feature on top of master.

The feature branch was done on top of 08c6f59, but now you're putting it on top of e0d2740. There may be conflicts.

```
git checkout feature
git rebase master

 * daf9f2d [feature] Require compatible...
 * 3547419 Public recompile.
 * e0d2740 [master] N/A
 * 6b2385f Apply Codestyles:
 * 08c6f59 Change vendor user...
```

- Fast forward master to feature.

Doing a merge on a direct ancestor will perform a "fast forward". There's no need for a merge commit, Git just moves the branch label forward.

```
git checkout master
git merge feature

 * daf9f2d [feature][master]]Require compatible...
 * 3547419 Public recompile.
 * e0d2740 N/A
 * 6b2385f Apply Codestyles:
 * 08c6f59 Change vendor user...
```

- Delete feature

```
git branch -d feature

 * daf9f2d [master]]Require compatible...
 * 3547419 Public recompile.
 * e0d2740 N/A
 * 6b2385f Apply Codestyles:
 * 08c6f59 Change vendor user...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
git checkout daf9f2d
git rebase e0d2740
# if this is what you want
git branch -f master
# push as needed
```

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: you won't be able to do that without changing the history of `master`.

If I understood correctly, you want to undo the merge and have the two commits of that branch be applied directly on to `master`.

Note that there's many ways of accomplishing this. Here's one that I would do:

This is the starting point:

```
*   a86813e (HEAD -> master) Merge branch 'branch'<Philipe Fatio>
|\  
| * 0c96fc9 (branch) B2
| * ec8db76 B1
* | 791f2e2 M4
* | c8b2a58 M3
|/  
* fa16cb9 M2
* 20beb8a M1
```

First, undo the merge on `master`:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

This gives us this graph:

```
* 0c96fc9 (branch) B2
* ec8db76 B1
| * 791f2e2 (HEAD -> master) M4
| * c8b2a58 M3
|/  
* fa16cb9 M2
* 20beb8a M1
```

Now rebase your branch on top of `master`. As it seems like you no longer have a branch pointing at the last commit before the merge, you'd have to checkout that SHA instead.

```
git checkout branch
git rebase master
```

This gives us the following graph:

```
* b79074d (HEAD -> branch) B2
* 829f920 B1
* 791f2e2 (master) M4
* c8b2a58 M3
* fa16cb9 M2
* 20beb8a M1
```

Now you can merge the branch into `master` with fast-forward (`--ff`):

```
git checkout master
git merge --ff branch
```

This is essentially the same as resetting `master` to the branch:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard branch
```

Our final graph looks like this:

```
* b79074d (HEAD -> master, branch) B2
* 829f920 B1
* 791f2e2 M4
* c8b2a58 M3
* fa16cb9 M2
* 20beb8a M1
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to simply use the rebase command. Rebase, by default, removes merge commits.  Be in the master branch, and use this command:

```
git rebase 08c6f59 #use the commit id of the latest commit you do not want to change.
```

This will create a single line of all the affected commits. You can also use git rebase --interactive if you want more control, for example to set the exact order the commits should be in.

Note that this changes history.  Normally, you should not change history for published commits as this can cause headaches for other users.