# Why are my --no-ff commits collapsed into the master branch after a git pull --rebase origin?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have a branch `master` which has a so-called "hotfix-branch", `hotfix/foo`, on that hotfix-branch, I have several commits, say A, B and C.

I then merge that into master with:

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff hotfix/foo
```

Resulting in a map/graph like I want it to be: one commit on `master`, introducting the net changes on `hotfix/foo` as commit D in master:

```
  _ A _ B _ C _   (hotfix/foo)
_/_____________\ D _ (master)
```

Now, when I update my master to make sure I am up-to-date with the latest work my colleagues might have pushed there, things get weird:

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

Suddenly, A, B, C are on the `master`:

```
_ A _ B _ C _ (master)
```

This probably is cause by the `--rebase` flag. I use that flag to avoid getting my upstream changes as merges into my `master`.

What am I doing wrong here? Why is it flattening my history, instead of maintaining the commits in the hotfix-branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using rebase with the `--preserve-merges` flag.

See here for some background: [git rebase "--preserve-merges --onto" doesn't preserve merges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521422/git-rebase-preserve-merges-onto-doesnt-preserve-merges)